# How to change binary (type 0x....) to String without the 0x?

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Trying to do in Databrciks SQL as in SQL Server :

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), @BinaryValue, 2)`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use [`hex`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/hex.html) function.

```
> SELECT hex('Spark SQL');
537061726B2053514C
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

- if you have a field of the binary type, then you can cast it to string using `cast(expr AS STRING)` or use the corresponding [string](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/string.html) function.  Although maybe it's better to use [decode](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/decode_cs.html) function.
- if you have a string field that contains hex-encoded data, then you need to use [unhex](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/unhex.html) function.